# How can we modify DOM element on template engines (ejs) dynamically?

Tags: node.js

In my NodeJS project, I am fetching a long list of data from a database (Firebase), and showing it to the user. For security purposes, I am doing the fetching in NodeJS (i.e. not on the client-side), and hence my current implementation requires me to pass this long list to my template engine (ejs). In my client side (i.e. my template engine), I have a a HTML element of a table, and I want to fill this with the list. The passing of the list itself is not really a problem, but the filling is what I am struggling with. The table that I am wanting to fill is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable" 
   <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="table_body"></tbody>
</table>
```

If I were to fetch the data from the client directly from the database, then this would not be a problem since modifications of DOM element (i.e. the table in this case) is allowed. However, since I am fetching from the server-side, and then passing the data to the client-side, I have no idea how to fill the table.

At one point during my struggle to answer this question, I thought about generating the entire HTML table on the server side as one giant string, and then shoving this on the template engine. I'm not too sure whether this is the right way of going about it though.

Comment: get an array from the DB then send a parm to the ejs .. in the ejs , pick it up as <%= array %>

Comment: Would that not just pollute the DOM with business logic?

Comment: But that's presentation logic, isn't it? The question doesn't explain what are 'data' and 'modifications' in your case. *I thought about generating the entire HTML table on the server side as one giant string, and then shoving this on the template engine. I'm not too sure whether this is the right way of going about it though* - this is the purpose that template engine serves. Depending on your needs, it may or may not be better to pass data as JSON and render the table on client side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190925/how-to-array-of-objects-in-template-ejs   another suggest for the list

Comment: Then how would people using logicless templates go about it?