# Loop generating empty lists

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, ejs

I dont understand, I'm looking on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190925/how-to-array-of-objects-in-template-ejs) answer but it just doesn't work for me. I get my table which is called bokad and then I want to loop the results.

[image]

My loop on bokningar.ejs

```
<ul>
  <% for (var loop in bokad){ %>
    <li><%= loop.bokad %></li>    
    <% } %> 
  </ul>
```

index.js

```
    app.get('/bokningar', function(req, res){
    pool.connect(function(err, table, done){ 
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching your bookings from table', err);
        }
        table.query('SELECT * FROM public.bokad', function(err, results){
            console.table(results.rows)

            if(err){
                return console.error('error runnig query', err);
            }
            res.render('bokningar.ejs', {bokad: results});
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

It's weird aswell no errors and the loop is generating like 15 empty list tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)  loop instead ,[for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is for objects

```
<ul>
  <% for (var loop of bokad.rows){ %>
    <li><%= loop.namn %></li>    
    <% } %> 
  </ul>
```

Comment: returns bokad is not iterable

Comment: no error this time and not 15 empty lists but now its only one empty list:/

Comment: you should return the property values of objects inside array ,check again

Comment: oh okey, thanks alot never understood what was wrong