# Displaying Array Information with EJS Templated

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I been working on a project in with I was looking to display the information of and array in EJS Template.
Once the Page load I find that the page is showing [Object, Object]
Is showing like this because the array contains 2 Object.
I'm just starting with Programing in Javapcript.

HTML:

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<p><%= hsContent %></p>

<% for (let i=0; i<postlist.length; i++ ){ %>
  <h2><%= postlist[i] %></h2>
  d
<% } %>
```

JS:

```
let posts = []

app.post("/compose", function (req, res) {
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    description : req.body.postBody
  };
  posts.push(post)
  res.redirect("/")
});
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code here so someone can help you. Show us what `postlist` is and how you are trying to render it within the for loop.

Comment: Hello Eyas, After continue my search I find I post, and tested a couple of the answer and find one that help me out.
Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: Also Update the information on the Post so more information is display for better understanding of the issue, but at the end of the day it was really simple, and from a beginner perspective just needed to pay more attention.

Answer (score -1):

After Looking a little I find this Post with a lot of good information.

[How to array of objects in template ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190925/how-to-array-of-objects-in-template-ejs)

Now this is how I resolve it from the information found on the post.

```
<ul>
<% for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ %>
    <li><%= results[i].title %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Thanks to this reply I could solve the issue thanks a lot.